# Is drupal a good platform to develop a custom requirement big project?

Tags: php, laravel-5, drupal-8

I have to develop a web application which contains the requirements such as fetching data from third party APIs, point out 100 of locations in Google map and create many reports based on API data etc. My client wants to develop this project in Drupal. I don't have much idea about Drupal, all my experience is in PHP Symphony and Laravel framework. I am confused that whether I should develop this application in Drupal or PHP with Laravel framework. Is drupal a best platform to develop these kinds of projects?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well obviously the "best" platform is going to be a matter of opinion. But remember, at heart Drupal is a Content Management System (CMS), whereas Laravel, Symphony etc. are pure frameworks. Generally speaking CMS's (like Drupal, WordPress etc.) are designed for the small business with a simple templated website. So if you're project is big and custom like you say, then the restrictions imposed by a CMS could make life difficult for you later on. I would personally go with a pure framework like Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand client's requirements. Actually, in PHP there are many CMS and frameworks are available for rapid web development. If your client for CMS site with strong admin panel then you should go for any of best CMS like Drupal, WordPress, Joomla etc.

Drupal is more secure and fast CMS system in PHP. There are lots of pre-built modules available that are helpful for rapid web development.

Drupal is best CMS. It provides the strong panel with pre inbuilt modules like view module etc.

Drupal provides hooks concept that is used to customize or filter existing functionality.

https://www.drupal.org/node/262422